# How to sign in to a cloud server from my Android Application using httppost

Tags: php, android, mysql, http-post, getjson

I'm new to Android Development and currently I am working on my project that involves signing in from my app to cloud server. And I have this very big problem in signing in from my android application to a cloud, the server runs a PHP script to search in the database for ID and password. The PHP code is below:

```
<?php
$myConnection = mysql_connect("mysql.hostinger.ph","xxxxx_user","xxxx_password");
mysql_select_db("xxxx_dbname",$myConnection);

$driverID = $_POST['driverID'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

 $query_search = "select * from users where driverID = '".$driverID."' AND password = '".$password. "'";
 $query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());
 $rows = mysql_num_rows($query_exec);

 if($rows --> 0) { echo "Y"; }
else  {echo "N"; }

?>
```

My Android code doesn't have errors and I can compile the project already and it runs smoothly, so it does not have a problem. But when I run the app in my phone, it says "Unfortunately, App Name has stopped"

My Java code is below:

```
public class DriverLogin  extends Activity {

    Button login;
    String driver="",pass="";
    EditText driverID,password;
    byte[] data;
    HttpPost httppost;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    InputStream inputStream;
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.driver_login); 
    // get action bar  
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    //showing action bar
    actionBar.show();


    driverID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDriverID);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDriverLogin); 


    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            driver = driverID.getText().toString();
            pass = password.getText().toString();

            if(driver.equals("") || pass.equals(""))
            {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please input required field", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {


            try {
                httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.net/myDBConnectors/signIn.php");

                // Add your data
                nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("driverID", driver.trim()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass.trim()));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

                data = new byte[256];

                buffer = new StringBuffer();
                int len = 0;
                while (-1 != (len = inputStream.read(data)) )
                {
                    buffer.append(new String(data, 0, len));
                }

                inputStream.close();
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if(buffer.charAt(0)=='Y')
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                proceedToAideLogin();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            }
        }

        private void proceedToAideLogin() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(DriverLogin.this, TourAideLogin.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });


}
```

}

Additionally, I've checked the manifest and i've added a permission already regarding the use of internet:`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Please help me. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Your PHP code is vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and has syntax errors: `$row --> 0`?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment, how can I improve it? I'm newbie and open for suggestions from you guys (experts).